# How to create N X N matrix from dictionary in python?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

i have the following dictionary

```
{0: 0.19061872333012447, 1: 0.17888063348969294, 2: 0.18075363706369463, 3: 0.17386644807451496, 4: 0.1685595168814177, 5: 0.17022621659717468, 6: 0.17022621659717468, 7: 0.1705066595213114, 8: 0.1724459452549653, 9: 0.16699495289779376, 10: 0.1685595168814177, 11: 0.16517166126189892, 12: 0.1669103234045191, 13: 0.17242860141627803, 14: 0.16702683033547178, 15: 0.16702683033547178, 16: 0.1666700007675641, 17: 0.16696046456756816, 18: 0.16702683033547178, 19: 0.16888240646253483, 20: 0.16702683033547178, 21: 0.16696046456756816, 22: 0.16702683033547178, 23: 0.17211910169417077, 24: 0.16839346362885932, 25: 0.16841048353251128, 26: 0.1668915879888551, 27: 0.17040007625796041, 28: 0.1687348348784343, 29: 0.17041693482266682, 30: 0.17054009067491258, 31: 0.17398839840712288, 32: 0.18394138457027406, 33: 0.19219463604407644}
```

with keys as nodes and values as similarity.
I created the following matrix from it using this code

```
orderedNames=list(G.nodes())
dataMatrix = np.array([katz[i] for i in orderedNames])
print(dataMatrix.shape)
output

(34,)
```

But i want a matrix with shape(34,34), how can i get it from the dictionary above?
Thank you for your help

Comment: what do you mean you want 34,34? can you show the first 5 rows of whayt you expect?

Comment: i mean shape @Onyambu

Comment: Can you first show the first 5 rows of the expected results